# Is There a Way to Determine _What_ is Being Changed In a DomainContext?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

If I'm working with a DomainContext and HasChanges is true, is there a way to figure out *what* was changed? The answer to that would be good enough, but I'm specifically looking to find out if something is being deleted, though it doesn't neet to be that specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the changes are being kept on the [Entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.entity_members%28VS.91%29.aspx) level. Each Entity has an [EntityState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.entitystate%28VS.91%29.aspx) that shows what type of change the Entity is in (that includes Deleted).
So in order to see what is changing or what type of changes are occuring, you have to look at each Entity itself. The good news is that each one of those has a HasChanges property as well.

Comment: Luckily, I had access to the entity being deleted and was able to check its state, so this full, complete answer was terrific. Thanks.